# Zooming in on a Google Docs Viewer PDF in Android webview

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I've noticed that Google Docs Viewer pinch to zoom won't work on some devices, is this correct? Can I switch it back on? On Android 2.3.3 it seems to work, not on HC or ICS. And the menu bar buttons that google viewer provides do not allow zooming in to sufficient magnification to read the small print in the PDF. Otherwise this seems like a good solution to putting a PDF inside a native android app. Any ideas to get zooming in working? Thanks!

Comment: have you found any solution? i need it too

Comment: Have you found the solution? Please post if yes

Comment: I'm sorry, this post is 3 years old and I don't recall ever finding a great solution on the few devices/OSs where this issue presented. I do recall investigating other PDF generation options, and I think that was our only option at the time.